# Rails - Loop not printing the data in liquid template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, liquid

I have pulled some records from database that look like as following and are assigned a variable called `users`

```
[#
<User id: 53433, first_name: "Héctor", last_name: "Pinzon">,
<User id: 53434, first_name: "Héctor 2", last_name: "Pinzon 2">,
]
```

Inside the liquid I want to iterate over them via loop

```
{% for user in users %}
{{ user.first_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

When I get the email where the `first_name` is supposed to appear it prints out

```
 Liquid error: internal 
 Liquid error: internal
```

What am i doing wrong here? Why the data from `users` does not appear?

Comment: Please post result  of `users`

Comment: already given in the question

Comment: What is the output of `{{ users }}`?

Comment: It dumps the users #53433: Héctor Pinzon#53434: Héctor 2 Pinzon 2

Comment: Your code `<ul>
{% for user in users %}
<li>{{ user.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>` is correct,I think this is not an issue of this code.

Comment: what could be the issue then, when i add a normal loop without any object that is working fine for example {% for i in (1..4) %} {{ i }} {% endfor %} its only the objects that it is not printing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150057/discussion-between-mayur-shah-and-saadia).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where ever you are passing `users` to your liquid template you need to change that to `users.map(&:attributes)` to get it in the correct format, we cant just pass the `users` object. After making this change then the following loop will render the data just fine.

```
{% for user in users %}
{{user.first_name }} {{user.last_name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an array of objects to Liquid but not another type of collection, like `ActiveRecord::Relation`.

If this is the case, `users.to_a` should work.